# STL Loader kept spinning

Tags: 3d

I am using three.min.js and works beautifully but the model is spinning endlessly. How to stop it and allow user to spin manually? And the spinning is off centered also, is there away to resolve this?

```
<script>
            if (!Detector.webgl) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
            var container, stats;
            var camera, cameraTarget, scene, renderer;
            init();
            animate();
            function init() {
                container = document.createElement('div');
                document.body.appendChild(container);
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 15);
                camera.position.set(3, 0.15, 3);
                cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3(0, -0.25, 0);
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0x72645b, 2, 15);
                // Ground
                var plane = new THREE.Mesh(
                    new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(40, 40),
                    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x999999, specular: 0x101010 })
                );
                plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
                plane.position.y = -0.5;
                scene.add(plane);
                plane.receiveShadow = true;

                var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();

                // Binary files
                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xAAAAAA, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 });
                loader.load('/productimages/mannequin.stl', function (geometry) {
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                    mesh.position.set(0, -0.37, -0.6);
                    mesh.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
                    mesh.scale.set(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
                    mesh.castShadow = true;
                    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                    scene.add(mesh);
                });

                // Lights
                scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x777777));
                addShadowedLight(1, 1, 1, 0xffffff, 1.35);
                addShadowedLight(0.5, 1, -1, 0xffaa00, 1);
                // renderer
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
                renderer.setClearColor(scene.fog.color);
                renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                renderer.gammaInput = true;
                renderer.gammaOutput = true;
                renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
                renderer.shadowMapCullFace = THREE.CullFaceBack;
                container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
                // stats
                stats = new Stats();
                stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                container.appendChild(stats.domElement);
                //
                window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
            }
            function addShadowedLight(x, y, z, color, intensity) {
                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
                directionalLight.position.set(x, y, z)
                scene.add(directionalLight);
                directionalLight.castShadow = true;
                // directionalLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
                var d = 1;
                directionalLight.shadowCameraLeft = -d;
                directionalLight.shadowCameraRight = d;
                directionalLight.shadowCameraTop = d;
                directionalLight.shadowCameraBottom = -d;
                directionalLight.shadowCameraNear = 1;
                directionalLight.shadowCameraFar = 4;
                directionalLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
                directionalLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
                directionalLight.shadowBias = -0.005;
                directionalLight.shadowDarkness = 0.15;
            }
            function onWindowResize() {
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            }
            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                render();
                stats.update();
            }
            function render() {
                var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005;
                camera.position.x = Math.cos(timer) * 3;
                camera.position.z = Math.sin(timer) * 3;
                camera.lookAt(cameraTarget);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

to stop it from spinning just remove the:

```
var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005;
camera.position.x = Math.cos(timer) * 3;
camera.position.z = Math.sin(timer) * 3;
```

from the render function or make a function to enable this part on click.